# Print an array consisting of string and integer without using function in cpp file

Tags: c++

I have this code in .cpp file and I'm **not allowed to edit the code in this file**.

```
#ifndef CP_MEMBER_H
#define CP_MEMBER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CP_Member
{
public:
    string m_name;
    int m_age;

public:
    CP_Member() {
        m_name = "?";
        m_age = 0;
    }
    CP_Member(string name, int age) : m_name(name), m_age(age) {}
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const CP_Member& a);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const CP_Member& a) {
    os << "Name:" << a.m_name << " Age: " << a.m_age;
    return os;
}

#endif
#pragma once
```

I've only written these on my .h file.

Comment: No-one is asking you to print an array. That's already being done in main. What you are being asked to do is print a `CP_Member` object.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `main` file is already doing

```
cout << newCommers[i] << endl;
```

You just have to make sure it does what you want. Since `newCommers[i]` is a `CP_Member`, you control everything about it, including what happens when you use `operator<<` on it. How to control this should be in your lecture notes, and you can research the problem with "overloading operator<<".

Comment: I have tried overloading the << operator method after looking up some information but I keep getting error message: while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, CP_Member). is it something wrong with my constructor or..?

Comment: @John try prepending the `friend` on your operator overload.

Comment: @John, @Rohan is correct. Since the first argument to the `CP_Member` is an `ostream` (`cout << newCommers[i]`, `cout` is an `ostream` and first, and `newCommers[i]` second), this function can't be a method of `CP_Member`. Rather you declare it as a friend function (this is another thing worth your time to research) and have it accept first the `std::ostream` and second your object.

Comment: I see.. i have edited my code but still getting the same error.. I will look into the friend function usage.

Comment: Ok.. i put the .h file into source files whereas it should be in header files... thank you all for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a `friend ostream& operator<<` because that's being used in `cout` statement:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const CP_Member &mem)
{
  return out << "Name: " << mem.m_name << " Age: " << mem.m_age;
}
```

After that, the program outputs:

```
Zhang San 22
Li Si 19
Wang Wu 18
Zhao Liu 24
? 0
```

Aside, you could use initialization list to construct:

```
CP_Member(string name, int age) : m_name(name), m_age(age) {
  std::cout << "Object constructed."; // Optional syntax
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm looking for some information on constructor cause i'm kinda confused with the notes given by my lecturer